# Are the rewards from Before Awakening, Anna's gift, Another Gift From Anna (free DLCs) 1 playthrough per game or save/route?

Tags: fire-emblem-fates

So title says it all. Basically are the rewards from each DLC only available once? For example if I was to play through all 3 routes can I only get the items for one of my routes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are once per playthrough.

I played once through each path (birthright, conquest, revelations), and was able to get Paragon and the Witch's Mark/Sighting Lens option on each save file.